# Define multiple responses for a single request when testing angular with $http-backend

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I'm starting to use `$http_backend` service from `angular-mocks` (1.2.16) in my protractor test suite.

I wrote the following mock :

```
$httpBackend
  .when('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/users')
  .respond(200, {
    "user": {
      "id": "5347b31750432d45a5020000",
      "name": "foobar",
      "email": "foobar@test.org",
      "authentication_token": "erqhglzerjaehregalergh"
    }
  });
```

... which perfectly works. But I also want to mock an error response like :

```
$httpBackend
  .when('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/users')
  .respond(422, {
      'message': 'Validation failed',
      'status': 422,
      'errors': [
        { 'resource': 'User', 'field': 'email', 'code': 'already_exists' },
        { 'resource': 'User', 'field': 'password', 'code': 'invalid' }
      ]
    }
  );
```

**Question** : How can I define these two kind of response ?

I thought about adding options in my url, like :

```
http://localhost:3000/users?test=success
http://localhost:3000/users?test=error
```

But, the action which trigger that call is in my test suite :

```
element(page.form.signup).findElement(by.css('button[type=submit]')).click();
```

... and I can't set options in the url here.

Do you have any other idea ?

Answer (score 1):

As these are two different test scenarios (success and error), it would make sense to simply define the data to respond with separately in each test declaration:

```
it('Should display error message if validation fails', function () {
    $httpBackend
      .when('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/users')
      .respond(422, {
          'message': 'Validation failed',
          'status': 422,
          'errors': [
              { 'resource': 'User', 'field': 'email', 'code': 'already_exists' },
              { 'resource': 'User', 'field': 'password', 'code': 'invalid' }
          ]
      });

    element(page.form.signup).findElement(by.css('button[type=submit]')).click();

    $httpBackend.flush();

    //check for expected response
});

it('Should respond with user information if validation successful', function () {
    $httpBackend
      .when('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/users')
      .respond(200, {
          "user": {
              "id": "5347b31750432d45a5020000",
              "name": "foobar",
              "email": "foobar@test.org",
              "authentication_token": "erqhglzerjaehregalergh"
          }
      });

    element(page.form.signup).findElement(by.css('button[type=submit]')).click();

    $httpBackend.flush();

    //check for expected response
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, if the code you're testing is relating to the submission of a form for example, the 'when' function can take an extra argument of 'data' allowing you to pass in the data that is entered in your protractor test and returning a response based on the data passed as well as the url itself.

Comment: Thank you @Kieren Hughes. Do you have an example of giving data to the `when()` function. I'm not sure to understand the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) on that point.

I'm agree that I may split in two separate tests, but in my point of view, I'm still testing the same element (the signup form)...